# Getting compilation error during building OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I am using Xubuntu 14.04 and trying to install the latest version of OpenCV, which is 3.0.0 rc1. Briefly, this is the error message I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(avpacket.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This error message was raised at 41% of the installation, when linking CXX shared library. Before trying to install openCV, first I configured by using `cmake` without flags. It said that openCV was ready to be installed. I don't know how to solve this problem and I am new to install packages from source. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like this is outside of your opencv compilation -- the library libavcodec.a on your system was compiled incorrectly. How did you install ffmpeg on your system??

Comment: I didn't have ffmpeg package in package manager, so I have download it from its official source and builded on my system. Is it improperly builded?

Comment: From the error it looks like libavcodec was compiled without the flag -fPIC, which is necessary to build a shared library using it (like openCV is trying to do). Try recompiling ffmpeg with `./configure --enable-shared` (and whatever other options you want) before make