# opencv V3 mixing shared and non shared

Tags: build, ffmpeg, cmake, ubuntu-14.04, opencv3.0

The current stable (V3.0.0) and unstable (V3.1.0) version of openCV is mixing shared and non shared libraries if compiled on an Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(avpacket.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.1.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Trying to create `libopencv_videoio.so` using `libavcodec.a` seems to be the problem. There is a [bug report](http://code.opencv.org/issues/4053) about that, but it is only giving the advice to check if `libavcodec.so` is installed (which is) and a workaround to use `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` to prevent creation of shared libraries. Does anyone knows the reason for this problem. The openCV people just state the Ubuntu packaged ffmpeg library to be not correct. Any idea?

The problem seems to be old. I just found a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953209) not answered but commented with the advice of compiling ffmpeg with `./configure --enable-shared`. But there is already a shared library `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so` which obviously is not found. I am not a `cmake` expert but couldn't it be a problem of a miss leaded build process?

Comment: Well, Ubuntu's ffmpeg packages are no real ffmpeg packages, but false-labled libavcodec library. Which is a fork. Beside that you could edit the CMakeCache.txt file and add `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so` to `FFMPEG_LIBRARIES` or a similarly named variable.

Comment: i think OpenCV 3.1 is more stable than OpenCV 3.0

Comment: Yes, it is just a formal naming with no quality statement. But none the less the official stable is 3.0. I am mainly using 3.1 with no problems that haven't been in 3.0 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thank you usr1234567**. You put me on the right track and the **problem is fixed** now.

It's all about avcodec witch isn't false-labeled in Ubuntu but for historical reasons false-labeled inside the cmake-files of openCV. But that was not the problem.

The problem was a bit strange search strategy of cmake looking for the libraries. It seems to prefer "/usr/local/lib" against "/usr/lib". Which is ok in general. But if there is a static lib in local with no dynamic lib it is using the static instead of searching in /usr/lib for a dynamic one.

So the lessons learned are; use `checkinstall` for proper cleanup of old attempts in local; be distrustful with the search strategies of cmake: *Do not expect umake to find the only dynamic library, if there are non distribution static libs around, even if the only dynamic one is in the correct directory.*